# Proving That Limit of Greatest Integer Function Does Not Exist using Epsilon-Delta

Tags: real-analysis, limits, analysis, epsilon-delta, ceiling-and-floor-functions

As part of my Real Analysis-I homework, we were given the following question:

> Let $ f(x) = [x] $ i.e. the greatest integer function. Fix a point $ p \in \mathbb{R} $. Using either of the definitions of the limit of $ f(x) $ as $x$ approaches $p$ -- whichever is more convenient -- discuss whether or not $f(x)$ has a limit as $x$ approaches $p$, depending on $p$.

I decided to try and do it using the $ \epsilon-\delta $ definition (although we have also discussed the sequential definition in class). My proof is as below, but I'm not sure if it is rigorous enough (especially since I wasn't able to define a $ \delta $ in terms of $ \epsilon $.)

Consider $ x \in \mathbb{R} $, then we know that $ \exists \ a \in \mathbb{Z} $ such that $ a \le x \le (a+1) $, as $\mathbb{Z}$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, by the Archimedean Property.

**Case 1:** Take $ I = (a, a+1), \ p \in I$. Then $ \forall x \in I, [x] = a. $ Fix $ \epsilon > 0,$ choose $ \delta_1 > 0 $ such that $ 0 < |x-p| < \delta_1, \forall x \in I $

Then $ |f(x) - a| = |[x] - a| = |a - a| = 0 < \epsilon \ \forall x \in I, 0 < |x-p| < \delta_1 $

Thus, by definition, $ lim_{x \rightarrow p} = a $.

**Case 2:** Take $ I = (a - \frac{1}{2}, a+\frac{1}{2}), \ p = a \in I$.

Then $
\begin{equation}
[x] =
    \begin{cases}
        a-1 & \text{if } x \in (a - \frac{1}{2}, a)\\
        a & \text{if } x \in (a, a + \frac{1}{2})
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
$

Let us assume $f(x)$ has the limit $L$. Then fix $ \epsilon > 0,$ choose $ \delta_2 > 0 $ such that $ 0 < |x-p| < \delta_2, \forall x \in I $.

Now $ |f(x) - L| = |[x] - L| < \epsilon $

$ \implies |a - 1 - L| < \epsilon \ \forall x \in (a - \frac{1}{2}, a) $

$ and \ \ |a - L| < \epsilon \ \forall x \in (a, a + \frac{1}{2}) $

Now consider $ 1 = |a - L + L - a - 1| $

$ \le |a - L| + |a - 1 - L| $ by triangle inequality

$ < \epsilon + \epsilon = 2\epsilon $

Thus, we have $ 1 < 2\epsilon \implies \epsilon > \frac{1}{2} $ which is not true $ \forall \epsilon > 0 $

Hence, $ \exists \epsilon > 0 \ \text{such that} \ |f(x) - L| \ge \epsilon \ \forall \delta > 0, \text{such that} \ 0 < |x-p| < \delta, \text{thus} \ f(x) $ does not have the limit $L$ as $x \rightarrow p$.

So, we see that the limit exists only when p is not an integer.

I'm not entirely convinced by this proof that I have come up with, because (as mentioned above), I'm not able to concretely define a $ \delta $ in terms of $ \epsilon $.

Please help me solve the problem I'm facing above, and also please find any other holes in my proof! If you can help me with an alternate, more correct proof, then that would be great.

**Notes:** (1) I'm a first year undergraduate, so my knowledge is a little limited - sorry if I omitted something important somewhere, but I'm open to learning! (2) This was my first time using LaTeX/MathJax, so I'm sorry if I did something stupid :(

Comment: This seems overly complex and inaccurate.  If $p\not \in \mathbb Z$, then $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is constant in a neighborhood of $p$, so the limit exists and is just $\lfloor p\rfloor$.  If $p\in \mathbb Z$ then there is no limit (just consider the two one-sided limits).

Comment: It's hard to follow what you write, but one error happens instantly:  knowing that $a≤x≤a+1$ for some $a\in \mathbb Z$ does not tell you that $\lfloor x\rfloor =a$.  It could be $a+1$.  What you should have written is that there exists some integer $a$ such that $a≤x<a+1$.

Comment: Right, makes sense. I know the answer intuitively (like you said, if p is not an integer the limit exists, and if it is the limit does not exist) - but I had a really hard time proving it rigorously as my assignment requires. Could you suggest a better proof, please?

Comment: Just formalize the argument I gave in the comments.  Start with the $p\in \mathbb Z$ case, as that is easier to formalize.  Then, for the other case, take $\delta = \frac 12\times \min (p-a, a+1-p)$, or something like that.